# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\alpha^+}\frac{2\ln(\sqrt x-\sqrt{\alpha})}{\ln(e^{\sqrt x}-e^{\sqrt{\alpha}})}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\alpha^+}\frac{2\ln(\sqrt x-\sqrt{\alpha})}{\ln(e^{\sqrt x}-e^{\sqrt{\alpha}})}$ without L'Hopital

Using L'Hopital, I am getting $2$ as answer.

I wonder how to do it without L'Hopital.

**Attempt $1$:**

In numerator, taking $2$ inside, I get, $\ln(x+\alpha-2\sqrt{x\alpha})=\ln(\alpha(1+\frac x{\alpha}-2\sqrt{\frac x{\alpha}}))$

Not sure what to do with it.

**Attempt $2$:**

Writing denominator as $\ln(e^{\sqrt{\alpha}}(e^{\sqrt x-\sqrt{\alpha}}-1))=\sqrt{\alpha}+\ln(\sqrt x-\sqrt{\alpha})$

Not able to proceed next.

**Attempt $3$:**

Putting $x=\alpha+h$,

Numerator=$2\ln(\sqrt{\alpha+h}-\sqrt{\alpha})=2\ln(\sqrt{\alpha}(\sqrt{1+\frac h{\alpha}}-1))$

Writing $\sqrt{1+\frac h{\alpha}}$ as $1+\frac h{2\alpha}$, but this isn't helping either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{\log(x-a)}{\log(e^x-e^a)}$ without using L'Hopital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050051/calculate-lim-x-to-a-frac-logx-a-logex-ea-without-using-lhopit) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Calpha%5E%2B%7D%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cln(%5Csqrt%20x-%5Csqrt%7B%5Calpha%7D)%7D%7B%5Cln(e%5E%7B%5Csqrt%20x%7D-e%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B%5Calpha%7D%7D)%7D%24&p=1). The specific question in this other post is basically equivalent to yours using a few appropriate substitutions.

Comment: Try $h=\sqrt x-\sqrt\alpha$.